Ubuntu 22.04.05 dual boot with Windows only boots to command prompt
Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04.05 as a dual boot with Windows 11 and everything worked, I could boot into either from the grub menu. Today when I tried to wake up my laptop from sleep/hibernating in Ubuntu, it froze and couldn't do anything other than power shutdown. Now when I try to boot up in Ubuntu, it only goes to the command prompt login. Windows 11 boots up fine.
